# Pausing MATLAB script until file is generated in directory

Tags: matlab, file-exists, pause

I have written a script which does the following: first it writes a text file to a specified directory, this text file is then called for a Post Processor via a PowerShell command which I also call in MATLAB in order to generate a result *.csv file. Lastly, the script formats the data in this generated *.csv file and plots the results.

The problem is that the script can only proceed once the given files have been placed in the directory - especially in the case of the *.csv file this may take 10-15 seconds. Currently I have simply added a sort of break point which prompts the user to wait, as follows:

```
fprintf("Check if *.csv is present in directory - then click 'Continue' \n")
keyboard;
```

I'm guessing there's a much better way to do this - ideally to run the script, automatically wait at a given point until a specified file is present in the directory, and then continue running the code.

How can I automate the check for existence of the *.csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the file `filename` exist using [`isfile`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfile.html) (post R2017b) like this:

```
if isfile(filename)
     % File exists.
else
     % File does not exist.
end
```

Pre R2017b you may use [`if exist(filename, 'file') == 2`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html).

You may combine this with a loop the following way:

```
t_Start = tic;     % Start stopwatch timer (to set a maximum time)
dt = 2;            % Check every dt seconds (example dt = 2)
while isfile(filename) == false && toc(t_Start) < 60  % maximum 60 seconds
    pause(dt);
    time_counter = time_counter + dt;
end

% Continue with your code here.
```

I'm using a while lopp to check if the file exist, and wait 2 seconds between each check. There is no reason to check every millisecond, unless you're in a hurry. You can of course change this.

`t_Start = tic;` and `toc(t_start) < 60` is a stopwatch that stops the loop after 60 seconds. Just using `tic` and `toc < 60` works too, but that would reset a `tic/toc` call outside of the loop, if there are any.

Note that `isfile(filename) == false` is the same as `~isfile(filename)`, but can be easier to read for beginners.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This works, however I notice that the script always runs for the maximum number of seconds specified by `time_counter` - 60s in your case, even if the file is generated much quicker. I tried changing the `&&` to a logical OR operator `||` but this has not worked. Do you have any insight here?

Comment: I found that if I specify the full file name including path, the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`exist()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html). This function checks for the existence of a variable, function, file, folder etc. Putting this in an `if` statement should do the trick:

```
if exist('your_file.csv')
    % Run your code
end
```

Comment: This only works if writing the full `.csv` is very quick. One could check if the file exists and the file size hasn't changed for a while...

Comment: I think the problem here is that if I want to check for the existence of multiple files in my script I would need fairly large nested `if` loops, since all code which is to be executed after checking for the existence of a file (the rest of the script), would need to be in this loop.